# Submit button enabled however when user enter input oldpassword it become disabled till reconfirm password how?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to enable submission due to condition while also when the user input in the old password field the button become disable till when the user enter the confirm password input the button become enabled again

Here is my attempt

```js
$('input[name=validationoldpassword]').keyup(function() {
  // not empty button is disable
  if ($(this).val() !== '') {
    $(':button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);

  } else {
    $(':button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label oldpasswordadduser">Old<br>&#10;Password:</label>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex">
    <input name="validationoldpassword" type="password" class="form-control oldpass" id="oldpasswords" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">Password:</label>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex">
    <input name="validationpassword" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="passwords" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$" title="Password should be like this. e.g. A123de!123">


    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="validationconfirmpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">Re-enter<br>&#10;Password:</label>
      <div class="col-6 d-flex">
        <input name="validationconfirmpassword" type="password" class="form-control confirmpass" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="btn-primary submitbutton">Done</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate

```js
$('#container').on("input", function() {
  const empty = $('[type=password]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().trim() === "";
  }).length > 0
  $(':button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', empty);
}).trigger("input")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label oldpasswordadduser">Old<br>&#10;Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationoldpassword" type="password" class="form-control oldpass" id="oldpasswords" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="validationpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex">
      <input name="validationpassword" type="password" class="form-control pass" id="passwords" placeholder="Password" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{7,}$" title="Password should be like this. e.g. A123de!123">


      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="validationconfirmpassword" class="col-form-label passwordadduser">Re-enter<br>&#10;Password:</label>
        <div class="col-6 d-flex">
          <input name="validationconfirmpassword" type="password" class="form-control confirmpass" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
      </div>

      <button id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="btn-primary submitbutton">Done</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: hi is it possible that the button leave it enabled but when the user type in the old password the button is disabled till the reconfirm password when input the button become enabled ?